# PHP timezone issue with the laravel application

Tags: php, laravel

When I am trying to start the existing laravel application it is complaining with the following.

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: timezone","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/PROJECT_FOLDER\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/start.php","line":167}}
```

I have already fix the time zone as the following.

```
date.timezone = Asia/Singapore
session.gc_maxlifetime=72000
```

But I am getting the issue. Can anyone give me suggestions for the next steps.

Comment: Could someone please suggest me the next step ?

Comment: Did you try to change timezone in `.env` or `config/app.php`

Comment: Yes I have tried

Comment: If you changed timezone during server is running, please stop the server, clear cache and start the server again.

Comment: Try to clear your cache using artisan

Comment: `trying to start` - what does it mean? Console command?  Visit web page?  Explain what you are doing in more detail. `already fix the time zone` - where did you put that code? Explain what you are doing in more detail.

Comment: can show function ? Get and Set both ?